# How to fill DataGridor any table like widget

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

Can anybody show me how to fill DataGrid  or any table like widget in Dojo when I have three arrays with values and I need to have three columns in grid (for every array one column, it is 1:1:1 between items from array, items are connected ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fill dojo grid from array](http://pastehtml.com/view/1duy1hy.html)
*Note:  you need to transform your 3 arrays in 1 like in example 
[Dojo docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/simple.html)